# Contains Query or Partial matching in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking to search a word say "amend" which may be present in data as  "amending", "amendment" or even "*amend". Which is the best method to search words like these?  I know wildcard can achieve this but I am restricted to not using it due to my other part of the code. What are the different ways which provides better search performance?

Comment: You can look into using The ngram tokenizer, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#analysis-ngram-tokenizer

Answer (score 18):

You can implement this using **query_string** feature of elasticsearch. Assuming that you use default `standard analyzer`.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "query_string":{  
         "default_field":"Customer",
         "query":"*Jo*"
      }
   }
}
```

You can add multiple fields as well as shown in the below query

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "query_string":{  
         "fields":[  
            "Customer",
            "Name"
         ],
         "query":"*Jo*"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: how to handle special char here?

Answer (score 5):

There is various way:

As you mention you cannot use wildcard, Then go for `query_string`

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "query_string":{  
         "default_field":"text",
         "query":"*amend"
      }
   }
}
```

Second you can use n-gram tokenizer. You can check here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

It will breaks your value "amending" to words like ["ame","men","end" ... etc]

Once you done with applying n-gram tokeinzer, Start indexing your data.

You can query like below:

`{"query":{"term":{"text":"amend"}}}`

You will get your output result.

Comment: I have indexed data as "amendment" but when using your query, it is showing no results. Should term be mentioned?

Comment: Which query u r using query_string or ngram ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing with the terms "amend", "amendment" and "amending" is called keyword stemming. You can add a [stemmer token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html) to your Elastic index settings.

For Example:

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "my_stemmer"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "my_stemmer" : {
                    "type" : "stemmer",
                    "name" : "english"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this stemmer will index the terms `[amend, amending, amendment]` as `[amend, amend, amend]`.

Then you can do a `match` query and it should return what you're wanting.